# Linux C: Accessing shared memory fails from time to time

Tags: linux, shared-memory

I already started a topic about this today: [Linux C: Accessing shared memory fails with `Invalid Argument` even though it was just created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60504242/linux-c-accessing-shared-memory-fails-with-invalid-argument-even-though-it-wa)

But unfortunately, the answer to that question didn't solve my problem completely.

I am still working with this function:

```
#define SHM_KEY 0x1237
int create_shrd_memory(uint64_t size) {
    int shmid = shmget(SHM_KEY, size, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL);
    if(shmid == -1) {
        if(errno == EEXIST) {
            printf("Shared memory with Key %d already exists, try to access it...\n", SHM_KEY);


            while((shmid = shmget(SHM_KEY, size, 0)) < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error access shared mem: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            }

            char *shdmem = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
            if(shdmem == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to obtain `Shared Memory` with id %d: %s\n", shmid, strerror(errno));
                return 0;
            }

            printf("Successfully accessed shared memory with id: %d!\n", shmid);
            shmdt(shdmem);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to obtain Shared Memory: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            perror("shmget");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return shmid;
}
```

Three different processes are accessing the shared memory (but each one is writing to a different position). The main process (which also starts the sub-processes via `fork()`) reads statistics from the shared memory and prints them every 2s:

```
void print_statistics(const int amnt_of_processes, int shmid) {

    uint8_t *shmd = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    if(shmd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to obtain `Shared Memory` with id: %d during statistics: %s\n", shmid, strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    printf("STATISTICS:\n");

    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < amnt_of_processes; i++) {
        printf("\tPROCESS %d\n", i);

        struct stats_record *stats = (struct stats_record*)(shmd + sizeof(struct stats_record) * i);

        printf("\t->REC PACKETS: %lu\n", stats->rx_packets);
        printf("\t->LOST PACKETS: %lu\n", stats->rtp_nmbr_drpd_pckts);
        printf("\t->Gbit/s: %0.2f\n", (stats->bps / 1024.0));
    }
}
```

The whole operation works fine but after three or four starts of my "distribution program", the shared memory can't be accessed anymore (the while-loop never returns which means that `shmget` always returns an error: `Error access shared mem: Invalid argument`.)

If I change `SHM_KEY` to a different value, compile and launch - everything works fine again (for three or four program executions). No problems during runtime by the way!

I cancel program execution by `CTRL + C`. My thought on this is because of the sudden interruption, the sub-processes aren't always able to call `shmdt()`. Can this cause the mentioned problems?

Comment: There are at least 2 reasons `shmget` returns `EINVAL`. Intrigued? Read more at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html

Comment: I don't see why any of the two reasons would be applicable in my case. Why would the memory suddenly be smaller than before? If less than `SHMMIN` or greater then `SHMAX` was true my guess is that I wouldn't have been able to create the shared memory in the first place?

Comment: _Why would the memory suddenly be smaller than before?_ may be because `uint64_t size` isn't a compile-time constant and you don't show where it comes from. Post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Try running your apps with `strace` and note `shmget` arguments.

Comment: Also use `ipcs` to see that you never free the shared memory.